# Solve a system of reccurence equations

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

$a_{n+1}=2a_n-b_n$

$b_{n+1}=a_n+4b_n$

$a_0=2,b_0=1$

Using generating functions,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}-a_0=2x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n-x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}-b_0=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n+4x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_nx^n$$

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n},g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}$$

Now we get

$$f(x)(1-2x)+xg(x)=2$$

$$xf(x)-4xg(x)=1$$

From this we get

$$f(x)=\frac{9}{4-7x}=\frac{9}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{7}{4}x}=\frac{9}{4}\cdot\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^nx^n$$

But this is not correct since $a_0=2$ and we got that $a_n=\frac{9}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^n$.

Then, for $g(x)$ we get

$$g(x)=\frac{5+7x}{4x(4-7x)}=\frac{5+7x}{x(16-28x)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{16-28x}$$

Here is another problem, finding (if exists), the power series of $1/x$.

How solve this system?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution
to get the generating functions.

I have shown every step
so any errors
can be readily found.

The method should be valid
even if there are errors.

Let
$A(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
and
$B(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_n x^n
$.

Then
$A(x)-a_0
=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n x^n
=x\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1} x^n
$
so
$(A(x)-a_0)/x
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1} x^n
$.

Similarly,
$(B(x)-a_0)/x
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} b_{n+1} x^n
$.

Therefore,
from the recurrances,

$(A(x)-a_0)/x
=2A(x)-B(x)
$
and
$(B(x)-b_0)/x
=A(x)+4B(x)
$.

From the first,
$A(x)-a_0
=2xA(x)-xB(x)
$
or
$B(x)
=(A(x)(1-2x)-a_0)/(2x)
$.

From the second,
$A(x)
=(B(x)(1-4x)-b_0)/x
$.

Therefore

$\begin{array}\\
A(x)
&=(B(x)(1-4x)-b_0)/x\\
&=(((A(x)(1-2x)-a_0)/(2x))(1-4x)-b_0)/x\\
\text{or}\\
xA(x)
&=((A(x)(1-2x)-a_0)/(2x))(1-4x)-b_0\\
&=(A(x)(1-2x)(1-4x)-a_0(1-4x))/(2x))-b_0\\
\text{or}\\
(xA(x)+b_0)(2x)
&=A(x)(1-2x)(1-4x)-a_0(1-4x)\\
\text{or}\\
2x^2A(x)+2xb_0
&=A(x)(1-2x)(1-4x)-a_0(1-4x)\\
\text{or}\\
(2x^2-(1-2x)(1-4x))A(x)
&=-a_0(1-4x)-2xb_0\\
\text{or}\\
(2x^2-(1-6x+8x^2))A(x)
&=-a_0+x(4a_0-2b_0)\\
\text{or}\\
(-6x^2-1+6x)A(x)
&=-a_0+x(4a_0-2b_0)\\
\text{or}\\
(6x^2-6x+1)A(x)
&=a_0+x(-4a_0+2b_0)\\
\end{array}
$

Putting in the initial values,
$(6x^2-6x+1)A(x)
=a_0+x(-4a_0+2b_0)
=2-6x
$
so that
$A(x)
=\dfrac{2-6x}{6x^2-6x+1}
$.

$B(x)$
can then be gotten,
but I'll stop here.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  written in matrix form:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\ 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{n} \\ b_{n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Let $A_n = \begin{pmatrix}
a_{n+1} \\ b_{n+1}
\end{pmatrix}
\,$, $A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & -1 \\ 1 & 4
\end{pmatrix}\,$ then $A_n = A^n \, A_0\,$ so the problem reduces to calculating $A^n$.

The [Jordan normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) $A=P\,J\,P^{-1}$ where $P$ is invertible and $J$ is upper triangular gives:

$$
P = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\,, \quad J = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\,, \quad P^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Since $A^n = P\,J^n\,P^{-1}\,$ the last step is to calculate $J^n\,$. Let:

$$J = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 1 \\ 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 \\ 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = J_0 + J_1
$$

Note that $J_0, J_1$ commute, and $J_1^2 = O\,$ (the zero matrix) so:

$$
\require{cancel}
J^n = (J_0+J_1)^n = J_0^n + \binom{n}{1} J_0^{n-1} J_1 + \cancel{\binom{n}{2} J_0^{n-2} J_1^2 + \cdots} = J_0^n + n J_0^{n-1} J_1
$$

Finally, putting everything back together:

$$
A_n = P\,\left(J_0^n + n J_0^{n-1} J_1\right)\,P^{-1}\,A_0 \quad\quad \left( \text{where of course} \;\; J_0^n = \begin{pmatrix}
3^n & 0 \\ 0 & 3^n
\end{pmatrix}\,\right)
$$